# How to speed up python code with many variable assignments

Tags: python, performance

I´m working on the following piece of code which creates a numpy array and uses many variable assignments to do that. The code was generated by Maple with optimization which results in lots of variable assignments. The code results from very complex mathematics and there is no further simplification possible with Maple.

```
    from math import sin, cos
    import numpy as np

    def __calc_tau(self, q, s_dot_v, omega_dot_ref, f_th, qm_ddot_ref):
        SC_param_est = self.SC_param_est
        SC_param = self.SC_param

        t1 = SC_param[3] + SC_param_est[0] + SC_param[10] + SC_param[9] + SC_param[8]
        t2 = cos(q[9])
        t3 = sin(q[9])
        t4 = SC_param[38] - SC_param[41]
        t5 = SC_param[35] - SC_param[38] + SC_param[40]
        t6 = t2 * SC_param_est[7]
        t7 = t3 * SC_param_est[9]
        t8 = t5 * SC_param[10]
        t9 = (-t6 + t4 - t7) * SC_param_est[0]
        t10 = SC_param[32] * SC_param[9]
        ...
        t638 = ...
        MCQ = np.array([[t1, 0, 0, 0, t37, t54, t54, -t127, t61, -t128, 0, -t126, t125, 0, -t91, -t106, -t106,
                         -t45 * t108 * s_dot_v[6] - t46 * t91, -t114 * t45 - t16 * t46,
                         -(t123 * t45 + t46 * t78) * SC_param_est[0], SC_param[7] * t124 * t1],
                        [0, t1, 0, -t31, 0, -t51, -t51, -t56, -t38, -t68, t126, 0, -t134, t129, 0, t131, t131,
                         t46 * t108 * s_dot_v[6] - t45 * t91, t114 * t46 - t16 * t45,
                         -SC_param_est[0] * (-t123 * t46 + t45 * t78), -t135 * t133 * t1], t86, t34, t36, t35,
                        [t54, -t51, 0, -t300, -t58, t89, t89, t115, t121, -t69, -t106, t131, 0, t450, t43, t55,
                         t55, t170, t76, t239, -t47], t10, t5, t2], dtype='float64')
```

I measured the execution time of the parts of with timeit my program and this seems to be the bottleneck with an execution time of approx. 3ms (Intel i7-8565U @ 1.8 GHz).

Is there a proper way to speed this up?

Comment: What makes you think it should be faster? Does it need to be faster?

Comment: That´s a very reasonable question, unfortunately the anwer is yes - it needs to be faster.

The reason is that this code snippet is from a algorithm to control a robot. If the calculation is too slow the system can get unstable. If the performance would be increased to 1ms for the calculation time, this would be enough to ensure stability of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further research and testing I found a solution. Using the `numba` package the following code worked for me:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def calc_MCQ_numba(SC_param, SC_param_est, q, s_dot_v):
    t1 = SC_param[3] + SC_param_est[0] + SC_param[10] + SC_param[9] + 
            SC_param[8]
    t2 = np.cos(q[9])
    t3 = np.sin(q[9])
    t4 = SC_param[38] - SC_param[41]
    t5 = SC_param[35] - SC_param[38] + SC_param[40]
    t6 = t2 * SC_param_est[7]
    t7 = t3 * SC_param_est[9]
    ...
    return np.array([[t1, 0, 0, 0, t37, t54, t54, -t127, t61, -t128, 0, -t126, t125, 0, -t91, -t106, -t106,
                  -t45 * t108 * s_dot_v[6] - t46 * t91, -t114 * t45 - t16 * t46,
                  -(t123 * t45 + t46 * t78) * SC_param_est[0], SC_param[7] * t124 * t1],
                 [0, t1, 0, -t31, 0, -t51, -t51, -t56, -t38, -t68, t126, 0, -t134, t129, 0, t131, t131,
                  t46 * t108 * s_dot_v[6] - t45 * t91, t114 * t46 - t16 * t45,
                  -SC_param_est[0] * (-t123 * t46 + t45 * t78), -t135 * t133 * t1], t86, t34, t36, t35,
                 [t54, -t51, 0, -t300, -t58, t89, t89, t115, t121, -t69, -t106, t131, 0, t450, t43, t55,
                  t55, t170, t76, t239, -t47], t10, t5, t2], dtype='float64')
```

With this function the first time executing the code takes very long (approx. 25s on my machine) but each time the function gets called again is very fast. I managed to get an execution time of 10µs - which is stunning compared to my first result.

Answer (score 1):

The many assignments are not the problem, but what is calculated in each case and then assigned to the variable.

From what I can see, there are a lot of mathematical functions like `sin`, `cos`  and dot products. I think these functions may be your bottleneck. Maybe you could try to reduce the number of these operations to speed up your function.

Comment: Actually there are not that many 'sin' and 'cos' calls. They are both only called six times. This was already optimized by the CodeGeneration function of Maple.